# Simple Search bar, that shows <div>

Tags: javascript, html

okay, I have been looking for some time now, and I have not been able to finde a solution yet, so I hope it's not a stupid question...

I Have made a very simple website, to show random recipes, when you just don't know what to make for dinner, and I would like to be able to also search for the recipes, if you know what you want, or just checking for spelling mistakes or what not...

the recipes are just text in a < div >, and I have made them like this

```
<div id="1" class="recipe">
<h2>name</h2>
<h3>stuff I need</h3>
<ul>
<li>stuff</li>
</ul>
<h3>how to</h3>
<p>how to text</p>
<h1>time</h1>
</div>
```

then I used this css to hide it

```
.recipe{
display:none;
}
```

and then I made a button that shows them at random with this (so far I have 15 recipes)

```
function RandomDiv() {
var myarray= new Array("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15");
var ChosenDiv = myarray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myarray.length)];

document.getElementById(ChosenDiv).style.display="inline-block";
</scipt>
```

I have no idea if theres is a simpler way to do the same, but so far it works
and now I would like to have a search bar in a < topnav > where I could write the name, and when I press submit it would show me the < div > the same way as the button does

I hope that this makes any kind of sense, and if there is something I forgot, I'm sorry, please tell me what I did wrong

Comment: other than you do not need an array, it is fine. Probably want to use `"block"` instead of `"inline-block"` or have another class that has `.reciepe.show { display: block; }` and add the class to show it.

Comment: You can implement a live search bar, as described here: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_lists.asp. Instead of hiding the ones you don't need, just show the one you want to see.

Comment: it's more like, I like when you open the site, it's pretty much just a button (and search bar) and then it only shows one recipe

and I must admit HTML and CSS, I'm beginning to get the hang off, but javascript, I get a little bit, but still pretty lost

so when I read
var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;

then it filters ul, li, a, and i?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nep, I've prepared a working example. In case of further question, don't hesitate to ask.

I've grouped your code into functions, comment out the random method and do add a nav with input to search for recipes.

```js
function getReceipes() {
  return document.getElementsByClassName('recipe');
}

function randomDiv() {
  var receipes = getReceipes();

  return receipes[Math.floor(Math.random() * receipes.length)];
}
  
// randomDiv().style.display="inline-block";

document.getElementById('search').addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  var searchText = this.value;

  Array.from(getReceipes()).forEach(function(recipe) {
    if (searchText.length === 0) {
       recipe.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
      var nameElement = recipe.getElementsByTagName('h2')[0];
    
      if (nameElement && nameElement.innerText.indexOf(searchText) > -1) {
        recipe.style.display = 'inline-block';
      } else {
        recipe.style.display = 'none';
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.recipe {
 display:none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <input id="search" type="text" placeholder="Type a name of recipe" />
</nav>
<main>
  <div id="1" class="recipe">
    <h2>first</h2>
    <h3>stuff I need</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>stuff</li>
    </ul>
    <h3>how to</h3>
    <p>how to text</p>
    <h1>time</h1>
</div>
 <div id="2" class="recipe">
    <h2>second</h2>
    <h3>stuff I need</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>stuff</li>
    </ul>
    <h3>how to</h3>
    <p>how to text</p>
    <h1>time</h1>
</div>
</main>
```

Comment: okay, this is really cool, thx man

when I "run code snippet" it's just perfect, but when i run it on my site, it doesent come with any resluts, and I was thinking, I did change the part 
return document.getElementsByClassName, because I tanslated the class name, so it would make sense, what it's really called is 'opskrift', so I changed it to return document.getElementsByClassName('opskrift');
is there any other thing i would have to change? since it not working?

Comment: Make sure that the input is being found using id: search, also make sure that there is a h2 element inside the opskrift container.

Comment: in the 'opskrift' container, the name is a h2 element, and the nav container? looks like this= <nav>
      <input id="search" type="text" placeholder="Type a name of recipe" />
    </nav>
is that the id:search you refered to?

Comment: okay I got to work, and it's just perfect, just 1 little thing is stille 'in the way', how to make it NOT case sensitive, when I search for ramen, I have to make a uppercase R, because thats how the name is written in the h2 container, and it's just not findeing it with a lower case r, so what to do........... and once agian, thx man,

Comment: To ignore case sensitivity in both ways you can replace var searchText = this.value; with var searchText = this.value.toLocaleLowerCase(); and nameElement.innerText.indexOf(searchText) with nameElement.innerText.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(searchText)

Comment: (insert thumps up emoji) thank you man (I think my other comment disappeared)